# Phone.NUMBER returns empty for all contacts

Tags: android, contacts

I'm trying to get a phone number from the Contacts with API 23 permissions, but the phone number always returns an empty string. Permission to get contacts has been verified, and the contact appears valid but the phone field doesn't seem to exist for any contact. "cr.query..." doesn't appear to bring anything back because "while (phones.moveToNext)" never shows true.
I'm using the below code to get the phone number. Any ideas why the phone number doesn't show up for any contact?

```
                ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
                cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                    Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId, null, null);
                    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                        String number = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        int type = phones.getInt(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));
                        switch (type) {
                            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                                // do something with the Home number here...
                                break;
                            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                                PhoneNumber = number;
                                break;
                            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                                // do something with the Work number here...
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    phones.close();
                }
                cursor.close();
```

UPDATE:
Not sure why that method wasn't working but found another method that does work.

```
        Uri result = data.getData();
        String id = result.getLastPathSegment();
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { id }, null);
    int phoneIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    PhoneNumber = cursor.getString(phoneIdx).toString();
                }
```

This method works fine.

Comment: can you write your full code with log cat error

Comment: There was no error, just empty phone string. I edited the post above to show a method that works.  The phone tested on is a Nexus 6P, in case that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try to use the following method to get the phone number details using the **ContactContract** :

```
private void retrieveContactNumber() {

    String contactNumber = null;

    // getting contacts ID
    Cursor cursorID = getContentResolver().query(uriContact,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID},
            null, null, null);

    if (cursorID.moveToFirst()) {

        contactID = cursorID.getString(cursorID.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
    }

    cursorID.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "Contact ID: " + contactID);

    // Using the contact ID now we will get contact phone number
    Cursor cursorPhone = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER},

            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE + " = " +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE,

            new String[]{contactID},
            null);

    if (cursorPhone.moveToFirst()) {
        contactNumber = cursorPhone.getString(cursorPhone.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
    }

    cursorPhone.close();

    Log.d(TAG, "Contact Phone Number: " + contactNumber);
}
```